# What is the reason of difference in distributed gate thyristor design

Tags: power-electronics, semiconductors, thyristor

As in the pictures, they use different designs (current rate, voltage rate etc. are same.)

What is difference between these two designs?

[image: Thyristor 1]

[image: Thyristor 2]

Comment: I assume it is the same reason other transistors do, though your thryistors look unusually pretty in comparison.

Comment: For any other novices that may need this: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-2/thyristors/

Comment: Here a picture for interdigitated T-network RF transistor https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Modeled-RF-BJT-layout-and-T-network-for-parasitic-characterization_fig1_2977826

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See first [this link](https://www.semikron.com/dl/service-support/downloads/download/semikron-application-manual-power-semiconductors-english-en-2015.pdf) ... See the "spreading speed" of 30-100 um/us ...
Semikron application manual Power Semiconductor, 2015, § 2.2.2.4

[image]

As long as the device engages in a "regular" way (at the maximum possible di / dt, minimal dv/dt) and gradually on all the available surface the current it does not really matter.  All the "arrangements" are allowed.

The only way to know which is the better "figure" is the "thermal" behavior of the device, shown with IR cameras.

*It would be interesting to have "notes" from manufacturers about the "migrations" of impurities which can also have a certain influence on the "life" of the component (and possible destruction) and that the "design" of the connections makes it possible to minimize these "displacements" by "driving" these impurities into "non-essential areas".*

See the conclusion (in french) of this "old" note : https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/jpa-00217349/document

EDIT : Incidentally, I came across this note ...  [Infineon Triggering ETT](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-AN2018-08_Triggering_ETTs-ApplicationNotes-v06_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4626cb27db2016cdcf641272e4c)

See paragraph 2.2 for what is called "amplifying gate" ... And conclusion 2.4.

Comment: The word you want is *thermal*.

Comment: @Hearth  JRE   ... Yes. Right. I update it.

Comment: Thank you for details. In Infineon docs, ,it says for amplifying gate is more immune to soft firing at Page 6. What does it mean ?

Comment: @Nott    I think, but I am not absolutely sure, that "soft firing" corresponds to the possibility of activating the ETT by a weak trigger current as it is possible to do with the first generation thyristors. It was supplied, indeed with these, a diagram of "command" for the trigger "Voltage .vs. Current" (with the limitations of max voltage, max current, hyperbolas Max power .vs. Duty cycle.

Comment: @Nott   It exists in this diagram shows a "forbidden" zone (called uncertain firing) located around Ug = 0 and Ig = 0, therefore low current and low voltage ... and which also depends on the temperature. , avoiding this zone, which is easily achieved by choosing the "good resistance" of the trigger with the help of this diagram.

Comment: @Nott See also 3.5 in the infineon doc.

Comment: @Nott  Here is the diagram for "forbidden area" and diagram about "firing correctly" thyristor (choice of "load line". Sorry, some text in french. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydjqG.png